# HTML: Coloring part of text in a line

Tags: html

Consider the following:

```
<p>
    <b>
        <div style="color:rgb(81,33,244)">Player1</div>
    </b> 
    to overtake 
    <b>
        <div style="color:rgb(187,4,0)">Player2</div>
    </b>
     in 1 hour 20 minutes
</p>
```

In this Player 1 and Player 2 are shown in different colors, however the 'div' breaks the line and it looks something like:

**Player1**

to overtake

**Player2**

in 1 hour 20 minutes

How can I color the players and yet keep them on the same line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use span instead of div

Answer (score 12):

Use an [inline element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) such as `span` rather than a block element such as `div`. In fact, given that the purpose of the styling seems to be to emphasize player names, I would say `em` is the most appropriate tag to use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
    .status em { font-weight:bold; font-style:normal }
    .player1 { color:rgb(81,33,244) }
    .player2 { color:rgb(187,4,0) }
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <p class="status"><em class="player1">Player1</em> to overtake <em
        class="player2">Player2</em> in 1 hour 20 minutes</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Style the `b` elements.

Comment: +1 for noticing that adding extra elements is totally redundant in the example given

Answer (score 1):

Change your div to span

Also, consider adding class attributes and putting your style information in an external CSS file.

Comment: +1 for class attributes.  The style doesn't need to be in a separate file.  Using class names instead of inline styling will help to describe the intent, making the code easier to comprehend. It will provide a centralized definition, which prevents shotgun surgery later, when you decide to change the colors.  It also reduces the need for the "b" tags, because you can attach font weight specifications to the class definitions.